# Brother DCP-L2530DW - problems with duplex printing

Tags: printer, duplex

I am the owner of a DCP-L2530DW printer and I use the duplex function.

If I select the "Long Edge (right side)" option in the "Duplex Print Settings" (in portrait orientation), programs such as Microsoft Word print documents in duplex mode correctly, without any reversals.

The situation completely changes when I want to print something in landscape orientation.

The function works, but there is a problem. The program remembers the settings from portrait orientation and prints upside down, and I have to change the "Long Edge (bottom)" option to another to fix the reversal. When I do this and change the settings, the vertical orientation also changes the settings, and in turn it prints upside down.

This is very annoying because I could not find the option to set separate duplex printing for portrait and landscape orientation. If I set the portrait orientation correctly, it ruins duplex printing in landscape, and vice versa.

I tried the "reversed printing" option, but the problem is that this option cannot be set separately for portrait and landscape orientation. It is set globally.

Please help. How to set up the printer to print duplex without printing upside down on the second side in both portrait and landscape mode, without the need to manually change different duplex printing options? What settings to choose? I tried different combinations, but what is good for portrait orientation prints upside down in landscape, and vice versa. If I set the landscape orientation correctly, then the portrait orientation is upside down.

I use Windows 10 and the original Brother drivers downloaded.